# Parse tags with beginning/ending markers

Tags: python, pyparsing

Below is a minimum example of the type of content I'm trying to parse and the parsers I've written to do it. There are multiple types of blocks (Records, Types, Packets), some of which may be nested, which are delimited by specific keywords.

```
import pyparsing as p

content = """
TYPES
   RECORD MY_RECORD_ENTRY
      char Name[5]
   END
END_TYPES

PACKET P1234 ID=1234
  DATATYPE NAME
END
"""

index_expr = p.QuotedString(quoteChar="[", endQuoteChar="]")
identifier = p.Word(p.alphas + "_", p.alphanums + "_")
mnemonic = identifier + p.Optional(index_expr)

# mnemonic
datatype = ~p.Keyword("END") + identifier
# not(END) because identifier will match too much
mnemonic_def = p.Group(datatype + mnemonic)

# record
rec_name = ~p.Keyword("END") + mnemonic
# not(END) because mnemonic will match too much
record_block = p.Group(p.Keyword("RECORD") + rec_name + p.OneOrMore(mnemonic_def) + p.Keyword("END"))

# packet
pkt_id = p.Keyword("ID") + "=" + identifier + p.Optional(",")
pkt_contents = p.OneOrMore(mnemonic_def | record_block)
# cannot be empty, may contain any number of mnemonics and records in any order
packet_block = p.Group(p.Keyword("PACKET") + identifier + pkt_id + pkt_contents + p.Keyword("END"))

# typedef
typedef = p.Group(identifier + identifier)

# types
type_block_content = p.OneOrMore(record_block | typedef)
# cannot be empty, may contain any number of records and typedefs in any order
type_block = p.Group(p.Keyword("TYPES") + type_block_content + p.Keyword("END_TYPES"))

# file format
grammar = p.OneOrMore(type_block | packet_block)
# blocks can occur in any order and can be arbitrary numbers of them

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = grammar.parseString(content)
```

I'm seeing the following error:

```
$ python3 tools/linting/mwe.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/linting/mwe.py", line 48, in <module>
    results = grammar.parseString(content)
  File "/home/wisp/.local/share/virtualenvs/wsf_fsw-fApZ1caW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py", line 869, in parseString
    raise exc.with_traceback(None)
pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected {Group:({'TYPES' {{Group:({'RECORD' ~{'END'} W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) [quoted string, starting with [ ending with ]] {Group:({~{'END'} W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) [quoted string, starting with [ ending with ]]})}... 'END'}) | Group:({W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z)})}}... 'END_TYPES'}) | Group:({'PACKET' W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) 'ID' '=' W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) [','] {{Group:({~{'END'} W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) [quoted string, starting with [ ending with ]]}) | Group:({'RECORD' ~{'END'} W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) [quoted string, starting with [ ending with ]] {Group:({~{'END'} W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) W:(A-Z_a-z, 0-9A-Z_a-z) [quoted string, starting with [ ending with ]]})}... 'END'})}}... 'END'})}, found '='  (at char 85), (line:8, col:16)
```

In this case, the types block is parsing past its end delimiter `END_TYPES` and into the packet definition before erroring. You'll see in the grammar, I've had to end some `~"END"` statements to prevent this from happening for some of the other definitions, which might be related to this problem.

In general, how do I properly specify a block delimited by starting/ending keywords? More specifically, how do I specify a syntax which will stop at the `END_TYPES` it's currently skipping over?

Using python 3.8 and pyparsing `3.0.0b2`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your parser:

- "1234" is not a valid identifier for "ID"
- `typedef` matches "END_TYPES" as a valid identifier for the data type.

I found the `typedef` problem by adding this code:

```
typedef.setName("typedef").setDebug()
```

(I also added a lot of other debug calls, but this one was the one that showed the problem.) Also,
adding `setName` calls will clean up your exception messages.

Some ideas on cleaning up your parser and fixing the problem:

1. Define your keywords once at the beginning of your grammar, then reference them by name where needed:

   ```
    RECORD, PACKET, TYPES, ID, END, END_TYPES = keywords = list(map(p.Keyword, 
        "RECORD PACKET TYPES ID END END_TYPES".split()))
   ```
2. Try using the `stopOn` parameter to the `OneOrMore`s, in place of using ~END in
   `identifier`:

   ```
    type_block_content = p.OneOrMore(record_block | typedef, stopOn=END_TYPES)
   ```
3. You can also define `identifier` as (don't need to add ~END in multiple
   places):

   ```
    KEYWORD = p.MatchFirst(keywords)
    identifier = ~KEYWORD + p.Word(p.alphas + "_", p.alphanums + "_")
   ```